# Bring enumerate back to numbering default

Tags: lists, enumerate

I'm using a nested list, where the outer items should be with numerals and the inner ones with numbers. I'm trying this with the package enumerate:

```
\begin{enumerate}[I]
    \item numeral I. This is ok.
        \begin{enumerate}
              \item I expect this to be "1", but it is "a)"
        \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

How can I make the inner item to be a number and not a letter?

Comment: Do you want *all* your enumerate lists to be this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\begin{enumerate}[I]
    \item numeral I. This is ok.
    \begin{enumerate}[1.]
        \item I expect this to be "1", but it is "a)"
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend the `enumitem` package, which is an improvement over the older `enumerate`, and is highly customizable and flexible:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\arabic*.}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[I]
\item numeral I. This is ok.
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item This is now ``1.''
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

There are tons of settings you can set with `\setlist` for each nesting level, [see here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf).